# Relacement mobile SQL(SQLite) to mobile NoSQL database

Tags: sqlite, nosql

Currently I have a project SQLite project on Mono for Android with 500000-1000000 records in database. it works well, but sometimes I have DB corruption. SQLite has a big list when db could be corrupted, so I tried to review some code but it still a problem , probably it happens with probability about 0.01 or less but it still creates some headache for customers because it's accounting mobile solution. 
So right now I'm trying to find some solution with different DB such NoSQL. 
If somebody has this experience with NoSQL mobile solutions please share it.
Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any indication that the corruption does not come from unreliable hardware? What makes you think that a different DB would have any less corruption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the possible choice  is  [ejdb](https://github.com/Softmotions/ejdb) or  [couchbase mobile](http://www.couchbase.com/mobile)